# VB Insert into MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

As a Vb noob im working on this school project. I need to insert my values into my mysql database but for a reason it isn't inserting tried everything but i can't find why it isn't inserting.
Thx in advance

```
 Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim SQLConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Dim strStockSQL As String
    Dim server As String = "localhost"
    Dim DatabaseName As String = "Gip"
    Dim userName As String = "root"
    Dim password As String = ""
    SQLConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
    Try

        strStockSQL = "insert into stock (Barcode,Naam_Product,Verkoopprijs) values (@Barcode,@Naam_product,@Verkoopprijs)"
        sqlCommand.Connection = SQLConnection
        sqlCommand.CommandText = strStockSQL
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Barcode", Convert.ToString(txtBarcode.Text))
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam_product", Convert.ToString(txtNaam.Text))
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Verkoopprijs", Convert.ToInt32(txtVP.Text))
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error occured: Could not insert record")
```

Comment: Was there supposed to be a question somewhere?

Comment: Is an exception occurring?  If yes, then please let us know what it is.

Comment: Nope I don't get an error from vb. Its just my Try Catch telling me the recorded can't be inserted.

Comment: If you are hitting the `Catch` of a `Try/Catch` block, an exception is occurring. Try: `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`.

Comment: Thanks. It says Connection must be valid and open.

Comment: When do you actually open your database connection.  It looks like you set SQLConnection to two different instances of MySqlConnection.  On the second instance, you ensure that it is closed even though it was never opened.  Then you set the connection string but never open the connection.

Comment: I saw it, I didnt open my database, stupid mistake.

Comment: Never hide exceptions from yourself like that .

Comment: @Plutonix We kinda never learned to use that, thankfully I know that now.

Comment: Never learned how to use exceptions? I'd be leery of that school.

Comment: Well Im kinda mad tough. They want a project wich uses databases never learned use how to work with mysql in vb so yeah Im now trying to figure things out but it isn't going that great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing an sqlCommand you must have it's related connection object in open state.

```
SQLConnection.Open()
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLConnection.Close()
```

Also, read about [`Using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement and use it for `SqlConnection`.

Another thing: this code line is meaningless: `If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()` remove it.

Comment: Thanks but out of the blue I got a new error Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server. I tried this connection before and it worked.

Comment: This is a different problem then the one you asked about. There is a problem either with your credentials or with your MySql server itself. I'm not a MySql server guy so I can't help you with that, but I'm sure once this problem is solved then the solution I suggested to your original question will prove to be working.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I get the one error after the other.

Comment: @Nordin you need to learn to debug and troubleshoot.  Asking for help with less than 5 minutes of troubleshooting is going to get you nowhere.  I'm not trying to be a jerk--this is advice I am giving in an attempt to be helpful.  You will never be successful at coding with this approach.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Thanks for the advice and you're right sorry for wasting you time.